# Tried to update cart item quantites using axios patch method: Error: Request failed with status code 405

Tags: laravel, methods, request, axios, patch

I want to update the quantity of item in a cart using **axios patch method**, so i want to test it first in the browser console but i keep getting this error.

**Error**

> Request failed with status code 405.

**The Route**

```
Route::patch('/cart/{product}', 'CartController@update')->name('cart.update');
```

**The Cart controller**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    return $request->all();
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div>
     <select class="quantity" data-id=" {{ $item->rowId }} ">
          <option value="">1</option>
          <option value="">2</option>
          <option value="">3</option>
          <option value="">4</option>
          <option value="">5</option>
     </select>
  </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
@section('extra-js')

<script src=" {{ asset('js/app.js') }} "></script>

<script>
 (function(){
 const classname = document.querySelectorAll('.quantity')

 Array.from(classname).forEach(function(element) {

 element.addEventListener('change', function() {

            const id = element.getAttribute('data-id')

                    axios.patch(`/cart/${id}`, { 

                    quantity: this.value
                    })
                    .then(function (response) {

                    console.log(response);
                    })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                         
                    console.log(error);
                    });

              })

        })
    })();

</script>

@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is with the url you are calling with patch:

```
axios.patch('/cart/${id}',
```

I assume you either have an $id in your blade file and want:

```
axios.patch('/cart/{{ $id }}',
```

OR

You want the id from the js:

```
axios.patch('/cart/'+id,
```

OR

Your syntax is working, but id is null or undefined.

Comment: thank you, i want the id from the js, but my syntax was wrong,                                              I tried this  `axios.patch('/cart/'+id,` still got the same error message in the console

Comment: Have you inspected the request in the browser to ensure it is being sent as patch? I cant imagine why it wouldnt since you are explicitly calling it on axios, but thats debugging :) Gotta start somewhere :)

Comment: yeah I checked all the request are coming as GET but when I try to update the item quantity from the drop down menu that's when I get the error (request failed with status code 405

Comment: You want the requests to be coming as patch. You have axios.patch and Route::patch() which should be good.

Answer (score 0):

as @KurtFriars said the  id is null or undefined. its because you use quotation instead of backticks so use @KurtFriars code or this:

```
axios.patch(`/cart/${id}`, {...}) // fill your code
```

Comment: this is the correct syntax I tried it but still got thesame error message in the console Error: Request failed with status code 405